# Photoshop CS6 Move Tool object borders

Tags: adobe-photoshop, cs6

When I use the move tool (when I move some object in the layer) I don't have the borders (dotted rectangle) around the moving object like here in this picture:

[image]

How can I turn borders on so every time I start to move the object they appear?

This is in my Photoshop no dotted lines around the object when I move it.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

If you have the "DisableDragBoundingBox.plugin" installed, remove it and relaunch Photoshop.

The "DisableDragBoundingBox.plugin" is an *optional* plug in that disabled the drag bounding box. By default, the drag bounding box should be visible (provided your graphics card can handle the OpenGL features).

As far as I'm aware, this is the **only** thing which will alter the Drag Bounding Box behavior.

Comment: There is no "DisableDragBoundingBox.plugin" installed. I have this in my System Info: `Adobe Photoshop Version: 13.0 (13.0 20120315.r.428 2012/03/15:21:00:00) x64
Operating System: Windows 7 64-bit
Version: 6.1 Service Pack 1` for the plugins: `Optional and third party plug-ins: NONE

Plug-ins that failed to load: NONE
` and for OpenGL: `OpenGL Drawing: Enabled.
OpenGL Drawing Mode: Advanced
OpenGL Allow Normal Mode: True.
OpenGL Allow Advanced Mode: True.
OpenGL Allow Old GPUs: Not Detected.
Video Card Vendor: NVIDIA Corporation
Video Card Renderer: GeForce GTS 250/PCIe/SSE2`

Comment: Before doing anything else, I'd update to Photoshop 13.0.6 on the Mac. You might want to rule out existing bugs which may have been already fixed.